# Play .MXF file in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, video, playback

We are looking for a web-based media player and Silverlight has been mentioned.
The requirement is to playback .mxf files with some HD content. In addition render the frame count on the screen during playback.

Is this possible with the current release of Silverlight?

I've had a look through the Expression Encoder site and it's not mentioned. Perhaps it might require a codec to play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [current list of codecs, containers, and delivery methods for Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28VS.95%29.aspx#delivery_method_containers_and_codecs) will help you.

As of the date of this answer, it currently does not support MXF as a container; you will have to transform the video into one of the supported formats in order to use Silverlight as a player.